# How to pipe() a grouped by key RDD?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I Have done the follow workflow path so far:

```
1) JavaPairRDD< Integer, String > aRDD = fooRDD.mapToPair( )

2) JavaPairRDD< Integer, Iterable< String > > bRDD = aRDD.groupByKey( )

3) JavaPairRDD< Integer, List<String> > cRDD = bRDD.mapToPair( )
```

Now I have a problem: I need to `cRDD.pipe('myscript.sh')` but I noticed `myscript.sh` are receiving all the list for each key at once.

The long version: there is a bash script that will take each group of lines and create a PDF with the data. So `bRDD` will group lines by using a key, `cRDD` will sort and remove some undesirable data inside each group and the next step will be create one PDF report for each data group.

I'm thinking in convert the `List<String>` representing the group content into a new `JavaPairRDD< Integer, String >` for each group but I don't know how to do this and even if this is the correct way to proceed.

Example:

```
(1,'foo,b,tom'), (1,'bar,c,city'), (1,'fly,Marty'), (2,'newFoo,Jerry'), (2,'newBar,zed,Mark'), (2,'newFly,boring,data') (2,'jack,big,deal')
```

After groupBy:

```
(1, 'foo,b,tom','bar,c,city','fly,Marty') 
(2, 'newFoo,Jerry','newBar,zed,Mark','newFly,boring,data','jack,big,deal')
```

How `myscript.sh' are taking the data (note one String for the entire group):

```
(1,['foo,b,tom,bar,c,city,fly,Marty'])

(2,['newFoo,Jerry,newBar,zed,Mark,newFly,boring,data,jack,big,deal'])
```

how I'm expecting to receive:

For partition 1 or worker 1:

```
1,'foo,b,tom'
1,'bar,c,city'
1,'fly,Marty'
```

For partition 2 or worker 2:

```
2,'newFoo,Jerry'
2,'newBar,zed,Mark'
2,'newFly,boring,data'
2,'jack,big,deal'
```

So I can process each line at one time but still keeping the group and can ensure that this will make group 1 go to one PDF report and group 2 go to another report. The major problem is my data line is already a comma-separated data then I can't determine where to start a new line value because all lines are merged as comma-separated line too.

I'm working with Java. Please give your answer in Java too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create RDD inside RDD. If you want to process all records continuously which belongs to particular key then you shouldn't again flatMap grouped RDDs ( bRDD, cRDD) . Instead, I would suggest to change grouped RDDs' ( bRDD, cRDD ) values separator to some other character.

e.g.

```
cRDD.map(s->{
            StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder();
           Iterator<String> ite = s._2().iterator();
            while (ite.hasNext()){
                //change delimiter to colon(:) or some other character
                sb.append(ite.next()+":");
            }
            return new Tuple2<Long,String>(s._1(),sb.toString());
        }).pipe('myscript.sh');
```

In `myscript.sh` split records based on colon (:). I hope this would help.

Comment: Good idea. Are you sure I'll have no problem when Spark dumps a bucket of data at once on my script? For some reason I think piping line by line is less dangerous than throw an entire bible at once but on the other hand I suspect there is no difference for the `stdin` stream ...

Comment: Thinking better: If I need to create a PDF report using the data then I must have it all at once anyway....